# Why does SQL Server's RESTORE VERIFYONLY command fail intermittently?

Tags: sql-server, restore

Our maintenance scripts run RESTORE VERIFYONLY WITH CHECKSUM after each database is backed up to our backup server. A few of the databases often fail with the error shown below. But if we re-run the exact same verify command manually later, it runs without a problem and says the file is valid.

```
Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Server SQL11, Line 1
Read on "\\192.168.168.2\Backup\DBName\FULL\DBName_FULL_20160214.bak" failed: 13(The data is invalid.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server SQL11, Line 1
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Why does VERIFYONLY fail when the maintenance plan is running but not when we run it manually?

Comment: Have you tried copying the backup locally and then run the restore verifyonly ?

Comment: Network blips due to a flaky / unstable / overwhelmed network perhaps. Copy locally like @Kin suggests before running the commands against the local copy, and I bet the problem disappears.

Comment: Kin, it works fine when I run the verify manually, even if the backup file is still on the network drive. I don't want to copy the backup file around as part of the maintenance job, because that will make it more complicated and slower. I'll look into network issues.

Comment: Is CHECKSUM necessary?

Comment: Maybe not. We added CHECKSUM as an extra verification. Why?